# How to make a symbolic function in MATLAB based on user input

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, minimization

I'm trying to make a symbolic function in MATLAB based on parameters input by a user and then minimize that function using fminsearch(fun, x0), which seems to only allow symbolic functions. I can't seem to find a way to generate an arbitrary symbolic function based on user input other than sym2poly(), which only works if I want to generate a polynomial function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `str2func` is what you are looking for:

```
% this is actually your user input, it could be taken,
% for example, using inputdlg function
user_in = inputdlg('Enter your function:','Function'); % '2*x + 4'

% the user input is transformed into a function handle 
% that can be passed to fminsearch
fh = str2func(['@(x) ' user_in]);

% the function created from the user input is evaluated 
x = fminsearch(fh,x0);
```

You could also let the used define the input arguments (but I don't think this is necessary with `fminsearch`):

```
str = '@(x,y) 2*x + 4*y + 1';
fh = str2func(str);
```

For more infos:

- [Official Documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html)
- [Nice Tutorial](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/03/13/using-str2func-for-anonymous-function-handle-creation/)

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't exactly what I had in mind, but it worked well nonetheless!